# Reading byte[] chronicle queue

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I am trying to write a byte array that I know the size of to the array however I am not able to parse the resultant data.

I am using the following code:

```
okAppender.writeBytes(b -> b.write(byteData));
```

and

```
byte[] byteData = new byte[500];
okTailer.readBytes(b -> b.read(byteData));
```

I expect there is padding but I do not know how much.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the chronicle Bytes class ( which can wrap a bytebufffer ) as reading into a byte[] creates and object each time.

Comment: You can use `Bytes bytes = Bytes.elasticHeapByteBuffer(128);` to create a bytes and `writeBytes(bytes)` and `readBytes(bytes)`

Comment: Why specifically 128 ?