# Chronicle Queue performance when using ByteBuffer

Tags: chronicle-queue

I'm using Chronicle Queue as a DataStore which will be written to once but read many many times. I'm trying to get the best performance (time to read x number of records). 
My data set (for my test) is about 3 million records , where each record consists of a bunch of longs and doubles. I initially started with "Highest-level" API which was obviously slow , then self-describing" data as mentioned in this [Chronicle Documentation](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue#using-chronicle-queue) and finally using "raw data" which gave the best performance.

Code as below:(Corresponding write() code is omitted for brevity)

```
 public List<DomainObject> read()
 {
        final ExcerptTailer tailer = _cq.createTailer();
        List<DomainObject> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (; ; ) {
            try (final DocumentContext ctx = tailer.readingDocument()) {
                Wire wire = ctx.wire();
                if(wire != null) {
                    wire.readBytes(in -> {

                        final long var1= in.readLong();
                        final int var2= in.readInt();
                        final double var3= in.readDouble();
                        final int var4= in.readInt();
                        final double var5= in.readDouble();
                        final int var6= in.readInt();
                        final double var7= in.readDouble();

                        result.add(DomainObject.create(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7);

                    });
                }else{
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

However to improve my Application performance ,I started using ByteBuffer instead of a "DomainObject" and thus modified by read method as below:

```
 public List<ByteBuffer> read()
{
        final ExcerptTailer tailer = _cq.createTailer();
        List<ByteBuffer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (; ; ) {
            try (final DocumentContext ctx = tailer.readingDocument()) {
                Wire wire = ctx.wire();
                if(wire != null) {
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(56);
                    wire.readBytes(in -> {
                       in.read(bb); });

                    result.add(bb);
                }else{
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Above code listing took an average of 550 ms vs 270ms for the first listing.

I also tried using Bytes.elasticByteBuffer as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271644/reading-byte-chronicle-queue) post but it was way slower

I'm guessing the second code listing is slower because it has to loop through the entire byte array.

**So my question is** - Is there a more performant way to read bytes from Chronicle Queue into a ByteBuffer? My data will always be 56 bytes with 8 bytes for each data item.

Comment: You really should be only reading one object at a time and processing that. This avoid creating a massive list of new objects. Allocating your object esp ByteBuffer is likely to be the slowest part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [Chronicle-Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/) instead of raw ByteBuffer. Chronicle's Bytes class is a wrapper on top of ByteBuffer but much easier to use.
The problem with your code is you create a bunch of objects instead of stream-processing. I suggest you read with something like:

```
public void read(Consumer<Bytes> consumer) {
    final ExcerptTailer tailer = _cq.createTailer();

    for (; ; ) {
        try (final DocumentContext ctx = tailer.readingDocument()) {

            if (ctx.isPresent()) {
                consumer.accept(ctx.wire().bytes());                    
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your writing method could look like:

```
public void write(BytesMarshallable o) {
    try (DocumentContext dc = _cq.acquireAppender().writingDocument()) {
        o.writeMarshallable(dc.wire().bytes());
    }
}
```

And then your consumer could be like:

```
private BytesMarshallable reusable = new BusinessObject(); //your class here

public accept(Bytes b) {
    reusable.readMarshallable(b);
    // your business logic here
    doSomething(reusable);
}
```